Json files not imported when using @nx/js:swc to build library
When I try to run code from a library that is built using @nx/js:swc and imports JSON files, I get "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" errors when running the code. The module it can't find is the JSON file. Searching the web says that this is because we need to pass --copy-files on the command line when building. I tried adding "copyFiles: true" to the options for the executor but that didn't work.

Nx exposes the "copy files" capability in project.json via the "assets" option. You need to include the JSON files here in order for them to be copied.
"build": {
      "executor": "@nx/js:swc",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/libs/abc",
        "main": "libs/abc/src/index.ts",
        "tsConfig": "libs/abc/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "assets": ["libs/abc/*.md", "libs/abc/**/*.json"]
      }
    },

